# Java Skype Api won't send messages

Tags: java, api, skype

I've started on making my own Skype app using Java Skype Api from taksan
https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api
(I prefer Java instead of C# because I don't know C# yet)

But my simple method on sending message doesn't work. I don't know if I'm missing something or they updated skype and therefore this api is outdated.

I tried two methods in Java FX called from a button. Both should send testing message to one of my friends. And yes, I've allowed the program in skype.

```
private void sendMsg2() throws SkypeException {
        Skype.chat("skype_ID").send("Sending test message ...");
    }

private void sendMsg(Friend[] friends) throws SkypeException {
        for (Friend akt : friends) {
            if (akt.getId().equals("friend's skype ID")) {
                akt.send("Test message 2");
                System.out.println("Sending test message 2...");
            }
        }
    }
```

Both have same results. Message won't send. Look at the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hbb6i.jpg
I'm trying to send message to one person (so it's not chat group). Any suggestions please?